# Automation of control panel > Wireless Network settings(802.11 modes) through Powershell or any other automated procedures

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powershell, automation

I want to automate the "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks" page in Windows through Powershell or any other automated procedures, to change my wireless adapter's mode to all the available modes and check whether the adapter gets connected successfully.

I was able to open until "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" through command prompt commands(control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter, control ncpa.cpl, control netconnections). But I'm unable to code to open the settings page.

The full naviagation that I want to automate is "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks > Adapter Properties > Configure > Advanced" and then I would like to change adapter's mode to the various 802.11 modes. I dont know Powershell.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 802.11 modes?

Comment: If you mean 802.11a vs 802.11b, etc, this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323949/changing-wireless-network-adapter-wireless-mode-properties

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this by trying to automate the GUI - i.e.: Starting with `ncpa.cpl` (you usually don't need to lead with `control ` for that, by the way) is pointless. That is, unless you're actually needing the user to watch or directly interact with the changes as they're happening. (And if that's something you're trying to achieve, PowerShell is *probably* not the right tool.) You need to have PowerShell leverage the direct access it has to the Registry, .NET Framework, and other back-end interfaces for these settings.

Comment: That said, the configuration of these particular settings are typically very driver-dependent. You'll need to learn more about where those settings are stored (it varies between manufacturers and models of equipment) and what the acceptable values are for them. Then, you might be lucky enough to figure out a way to make PowerShell do the work for you. Unfortunately, as you say you "don't know PowerShell" to begin with, I'm afraid this is a task you're not well-suited for. It's also not something we'll likely be able to help without actually being in control of your system.